# Ajax jquery json array output problem

Tags: jquery, json

When i get an json_encoded array with ajax json, i'm output the elements like the usual array

element[0]

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'url.php',                
  data: "",                                       
  dataType: 'json',                    
  success: function(element)        
  {   
    $('#content').html(element[0]);
  } 
});
```

I get the infro from encoded json thtat is in the url, but it only outputs [object Object]

Comment: 'like the usual array' is the part that makes this not work here. Try to dump the jSon object here ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well maybe there are some properties for this element. For example if the returned JSON looked like this:

```
[ { "someProperty": "value 1" }, { "someProperty": "value 2" } ]
```

you could:

```
$('#content').html(element[0].someProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `toString()` of an object returns `[object Object]`.

You need to decide how to output that `Object`. Check its properties, and choose the ones you need, e.g. `element.something`.